Are questions about admin tools and capabilities of web apps on topic?
On this question, it's being argued that admin tools aren't on topic. It's not clear where that comes from. The FAQ entry doesn't advise on this at all. and this position doesn't make much sense to me.
The site FAQ does say,

Are questions about corporate applications on topic?

Which is answered that they are on topic.
It would seem bizarre if these applications were on topic only for questions at specific privilege levels, or for non-admins only. There are two potential questions that should be answered:

Are questions that are about admin capabilities and interfaces on topic?
Are questions from a user-perspective on admin capabilities on topic?

It seems we have a lot of answers on admin interfaces,

How do I add an external administrator to a Google Suite?
Accessing a Facebook page as an administrator after account cancelation
Can the administrator download/mirror everyone's email from Google Apps for Business? (which is a very similar question)



Are questions about admin tools and capabilities of web apps on topic?

If the admin panel is a web app, then it is on topic (assuming that the question isn't off-topic for some other reason).
E.g., one can access the MS Teams admin center at https://admin.teams.microsoft.com and the MS 365 admin center at
https://aka.ms/admincenter, so questions about this online MS Teams and MS 365 admin panels are on topic.

I agree with you, and I also have stated/clarified that in my answer.


It seems we have a lot of answers on admin interfaces

Three answers hardly makes that case however I'm happy to concede the point as I don't think the volume of questions about admin interfaces is directly relevant here.

How do I add an external administrator to a Google Suite?
This question is well-scoped to a specific problem: adding an external account as an administrator.
Accessing a Facebook page as an administrator after account cancelation
This is a 13-year-old question, that asks what happens to a page if its sole admin has their account canceled. This question could benefit from additional details (type of page, do they mean suspended or self-deleted?) but is reasonably scoped.
Can the administrator download/mirror everyone's email from Google Apps for Business?
This is a 12-year-old question that is reasonably scoped.


it's being argued that admin tools aren't on topic

Not intentionally although I can see how it is a reasonable interpretation. I felt it was a better fit for Server Fault and summarized how it seemed to meet their on-topic FAQ. I agree that merely being about admin tools doesn't disqualify it from Web Apps.

Original Question
Does Microsoft Teams tooling allow administrators to see users with LinkedIn accounts that are looking for a job?
If I link my work's Microsoft Team's account, do they have optics into
when I'm looking  for a new job? I'm concerned about giving
administration that functionality, and I'm curious to know if LinkedIn
has protected us from that risk?

To be fair you aren't asking about a specific admin tool but a broad question about non-specific capabilities available within the administration tools specific to your employer's IT platform. There should be a specific problem to solve that is reasonably scoped.
I remain concerned that the scope of the question would also be an issue for Server Fault and it isn't clear to me whether your org's infrastructure (management, hosting, specific platforms/options) would have implications for its suitability on their site. I'm sure they would be able to provide insight if you, or I if you wish me to, enquired.
Your question is not reasonably scoped
The question isn't a good fit for the site because it isn't reasonably scoped to the functions of a particular web app, or a problem you are experiencing.

We have no insight into what your org's MS-365 Enterprise products and versions are, what options they subscribe to, etc.
We have no insight into your accounts' permissions, your configuration choices in the apps, group policies that are applied, etc.
We have no insight into what constitutes "all the information" that could indicate to your employer that you are looking for a job, or what information you are currently generating in LinkedIn, nor how you have configured your settings.
We don't know what you mean by being protected by LinkedIn. That they follow their policies? That they don't permit you to share information? That they provide you with tools to control what information you share?
We are missing information related to your behavior, your organization's platform and configuration, your LinkedIn account type and configuration including any add-ons and connected accounts.

A few good places for you to start if interested:

Manage your LinkedIn account and privacy settings
Control Microsoft accounts you give access to your LinkedIn data
LinkedIn's Privacy Policy

Data We Collect
How We Use Your Data
How We Share Information
Your Choices and Obligations
Other Important Information


Ask questions about LinkedIn's Privacy Policy
Contact LinkedIn's Data Protection Officer

Additional LinkedIn resources you may find helpful

Visibility: Control who can see your profile, network, and LinkedIn activity.
Permitted services:  Services to which you have granted access to your LinkedIn profile and network data.
Off-LinkedIn Visibility: Show information from your profile to users of permitted services such as Outlook?
Data Privacy: Configure privacy and security settings related to how LinkedIn uses your data, job-seeking preferences, and other applications. You’re also able to manage your messages and download your account data
Use data for research: Enable trusted third-party partners to use data about you for social, economic, and workplace research
Access the Who's viewed your profile feature

Other links

LinkedIn and Microsoft Entra IDs
Risk and compliance solutions > Content search in Microsoft Teams
Managing your LinkedIn account privacy settings


We have 550 questions with the word "admin" in them. I'm not going to disqualify them individually but it would seem many can be cited to show the acceptability. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=admin+is%3Aquestion

@EvanCarroll I agree with you that it is not a good reason to disqualify a question.

So we agree on that, and we agree it's an unrelated conversation about whether or not this is on topic on ServerFault -- their topicality doesn't define any other site. I don't understand why the capabilities of third party Web Application plugins would exclude questions here then.

Take for example this question: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/171122/is-it-possible-to-list-cards-horizontally/171157#171157 "Is it possible to list cards horizontally?" about Trello. Your answer was basically, "it's not possible without a plugin, but here is a plugin that makes it possible." If the question was instead, "Is it possible to list cards horizontally with or without a plugin?" would it then be off-topic? These seem pretty close to me...

I wish the rest of your questions were brought up in the comments instead of the "admin interface" reason. "Protect" in the context of the question means data not made available to plugin and third party authors using the Office 365 API. If that information isn't shared, or available -- you're safe from any plugin being built which does this.

You can access the docs about what LinkedIn shares (and what they don't) combined with what you have agreed to (and disallowed), and see if that addresses your concerns. You have LinkedIn, your org, Microsoft, and yourself all involved in your question with competing interests combined with agreements you have made personally in the interface that are unknown to us. Are you using your orgs teams account to communicate with employers?
